# Extracting multiple segments from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on gathering up a list of image sequences from multiple directories.  I'm using a TCL expression within Nuke (compositing package) to generate a sting that lists the contents of each directory.  The returned string looks like so:

```
Draft {Test_02_v002_Global_alp_%04d.png 1-12} {Test_02_v002_Global_col_%04d.png 1-12} Thumbs.db
```

The Draft and Thumbs.db are unwanted parts of the string (non-image files within the directory).  What I want to get is this:

```
Test_02_v002_Global_alp_%04d.png 1-12 

Test_02_v002_Global_col_%04d.png 1-12
```

I am able to do this if there is only one image sequence in the directory using the following code:

```
start = "{"
end = "}"
re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), string).group(1)
```

But I can't figure out how to get this to work when more than one image sequence exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> mystr = "Draft {Test_02_v002_Global_alp_%04d.png 1-12} {Test_02_v002_Global_col_%04d.png 1-12} Thumbs.db"
>>> findall("{(.*?)}", mystr)
['Test_02_v002_Global_alp_%04d.png 1-12', 'Test_02_v002_Global_col_%04d.png 1-12']
>>>
```

Comment: Excellent thank you!  This can actually replace my previous regex.